# How to use val instead of var in scala

Tags: java, scala, if-statement, collections, functional-programming

I simply want to remove var and use Val instead in below code

```
def getConfigId: Long = {
val object1: java.util.List[objectA] = objectRepo.findByUser(User(session.id))

var object2: objectA = null
if (object1.size() == 1) {
  object2 = object1.get(0)
} else if (object1.size() > 1) {
  object2 = object1.get(0)
  object1.forEach(a => if (a.endDate.compareTo(object2.endDate) >= 0) {
    object2 = a
  })
}
object2.configId
}
```

I am trying to use case match, but it's not working

```
def getConfigId: Long = {
val object1: java.util.List[objectA] = objectRepo.findByUser(User(session.id))

val object2: objectA = {
  case x if object1.size() == 1 => object1.get(0)

  case x => if (object1.size() > 1) {
    object1.get(0)
    object1.forEach(a => if(a.endDate.compareTo(object2.endDate) >= 0) {
     object2 = a
   })
}
```

Comment: `val object2: objectA = object1.findLast(_.endDate.compareTo(object1.get(0).endDate >= 0))`

Comment: @jwvh thank you for the reply but I got solution from esse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is:

```
import scala.jdk.javaapi.CollectionConverters

def getConfigId: Long = {
  val values = objectRepo.findByUser(User(session.id))
  val index = values.asScala.map(_.endDate).zipWithIndex.max._2
  values.get(index).configId
}
```

Or:

```
import scala.jdk.javaapi.CollectionConverters

def getConfigId: Long = 
  objectRepo.findByUser(User(session.id)).asScala.reverse.maxBy(_.endDate).configId
```

Comment: It's shouldn't be the latest, but last in the list given it's not earlier than the first element.

Answer (score 4):

`if` is an expression in Scala - it returns a resulting value. This means, you can keep your logic and simply assign the returned value of an `if` statement to the variable:

```
var object2: objectA = if (object1.size() == 1) {
    object1.get(0)
  } else if (object1.size() > 1) {
    object1
      .filter(a => (a.endDate.compareTo(object1.get(0).endDate) >= 0))
      .lastOption
      .orElse(Some(object1.get(0)))
      .get
  }
```

Or even easier:

```
val object2 = object1
      .filter(a => (a.endDate.compareTo(object1.get(0).endDate) >= 0))
      .last
```

Comment: @jwvh you're right, I didn't notice that, thank you!

Comment: Btw, your two solution are both wrong:), e.g. for dates: [1, 2, 3, 4, 1], you will get the latest 1, not 4.

Comment: @esse that's the same as in the question, as already said, it's not the latest

Comment: @Andronicus thank you for the reply but I got solution from esse

Comment: @Rohan it results in a completely different value, but ok